# I'm trying to get a list of all Postgre SQl Databases in my Azure subscription via powershell, but can't find a query for it

Tags: postgresql, azure, powershell

Do anyone know of if there is  a way to do this or have any articles where something similar to this is done?

Comment: After less than five seconds of googling I found this API page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/postgresql/singleserver/servers/list Do you know how to get started with this? Do you know how to call a REST API in Powershell?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid See my answer.  In Powershell it does the same thing as the Azure Rest API you found.

Comment: You're correct, Powershell does the same thing. It's just a wrapper around the REST API after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Get-AzPostgreSqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.postgresql/get-azpostgresqlserver?view=azps-5.8.0) to list the Postgre SQl Databases in an Azure subscription.

```
# Install the Azure Az PowerShell module
Install-Module -Name Az -Scope CurrentUser -Repository PSGallery -Force

# Connect to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription {subscription id} -Tenant {tenant id}

# Install the Az.PostgreSql module
Install-Module -Name Az.PostgreSql -RequiredVersion 0.5.0

# List the Postgre SQl Databases in an Azure subscription
Get-AzPostgreSqlServer -SubscriptionId {subscription id}
```